# Limits of Congress’ override authority

Tags: united-states, president, congress, budget, veto

With regards to the annual budget for the U.S. government.  If congress approved a budget that was then vetoed by the president, could congress use its override authority to approve the budget and fund the government for the fiscal year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

That is exactly what the override does, if 2/3 of each house agree the president's opinions don't matter.

Comment: So there are no limitations on the type of bill, all types are equal and can be over-ridden if 2/3 of congress agrees?

Comment: @Aaron revenue bills must originate in the house, other than that types aren't meaningful.

Comment: @aaron: Not entirely: If the executive or judicial branches oppose a bill on the basis not of disagreement but that it violates the Constitution, the amendment process would be needed to push it through, which requires not only a supermajority in Congress but also ratification by the states.

Comment: @BenVoigt: an Act of Congress is assumed to be constitutional unless and until the Supreme Court rules otherwise. If the court strikes down all or part of an act, then the government could attempt to get new legislation through Congress to get around that, or go down the lengthy path of a constitutional amendment.

Comment: @BenVoigt  If you think a broader or more detailed answer is called for make it and get some points. I read this question as asking for unambiguity rather than depth.

Comment: @Aaron: The biggest limit is that you need 2/3 of congress to agree on it. Right now, it's enough trouble getting 50% to agree on even a basic budget! In the history of the U.S. there have been 110 overridden vetoes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_presidential_vetoes), which is roughly one every 2 or 3 years. And note that Ford, Truman, and Johnson account for over 1/3 of overridden vetoes.

Comment: @Ethan that was one of my thoughts in asking the question. In our current environment we can barely get 50% of them to agree and it’s scary to think that is the best that a party that controls congress and the White House can do. What would happen with regards to budget would happen if the president demands that something he wants be in the budget and it isn’t and he vetos it.  I wasn’t entirely sure that a budget could be forced in if the president wholeheartedly rejects it based on it missing what he wanted but congress and the people don’t.